# Should I trash a program after "Test Run" and then "Scavenge"?

Tags: android-netrunner

I use [Test Run](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/25045) to install a program. Magnum Opus for example. Then I use [Scavenge](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03034) to trash the Magnum Opus and install it back. Should I trash the Magnum Opus at the end of the turn?

[image: Test Run] [image: Scavenge]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, when you Scavenge the Magnum Opus and reinstall it, it's considered a new copy of that program, not the same one which was installed originally with Test Run, which no longer has a valid target for moving to the top of your stack at the end of the turn.

See 8.2.10 in the [NISEI Comprehensive Rules](https://nisei.net/files/Comprehensive_Rules.pdf):

> Whenever a card is uninstalled, there is no memory of its previous
>   state, and it is considered to be a new copy of the card.